# GraphicsUnit.Point or Pixel or world for printer?

Tags: c#, printing

i am making a desktop application using c# with VS2010 , the purpose of the app is to fill in a form (the form is a physical paper that has spaces in it) so my program has to print the text that i want in the exact place that i need it to be printed on.

my code goes like this:

```
private void urinePrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender,System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        //## event handler for urine printing

        string FieldValue = ""; // to hold the current text to be printed
        SolidBrush BlackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Font MyFont = new Font("Arial", 12, GraphicsUnit.Point); //the font to be used
        int myFontHeight = (int)(MyFont.GetHeight(e.Graphics));
        int CurrentX, CurrentY;

        //millimeter XXXX
        //inch  XXXXX
        //display - error
        //Document - very small

        // 100 Pixel = 1 inch
        //100 Point - 1 inch
        // 100 world - 1 inch

        CurrentX = 0;
        CurrentY = 0;
        FieldValue = ptName;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(FieldValue, MyFont, BlackBrush, CurrentX, CurrentY);

        CurrentX = 100;
        CurrentY = 100;
        FieldValue = ptFileNumber;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(FieldValue, MyFont, BlackBrush, CurrentX, CurrentY);


    }
```

my question is regarding the line

```
Font MyFont = new Font("Arial", 12, GraphicsUnit.Point); //the font to be used
```

specifically the GraphicsUnit.Point enumerator. we have got GraphicsUnit.Point ,millimeter ,inch,display ,Document,Pixel ,Point and world . i have tried them all and found that the last 3 print the text as expected and seem to "displace" the text one inch for each 100 units. i need my code to produce the same result on all type of printers is there any difference between the 3 ? and which one i should use to print on a printer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you draw to paper is automatically scaled to fit the printer resolution, it is not affected by font sizes at all.  The default scaling is GraphUnit.Display, a scaling that maps 100 pixels to an inch, you already discovered it.  It is a handy scaling mode since monitors are usually set to 96 dots per inch so everything you print will (almost) be the same size as it it shows on the screen.

The size of the font you create is only relevant to exactly where you draw text on paper.  In other words, the PointF.Y value you pass to Graphics.DrawString().  You need to know the line spacing of the font in pixels, not points, use MyFont.Height.